# To plot this .Mat list data in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I loaded the data by

```
import scipy.io
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
data = scipy.io.loadmat('arrytmia_data_bad.mat')
```

I see it as

```
>>> data
{'__version__': '1.0', 'data': array([[-0.01782227],
       [-0.02450562],
       [-0.02227783],
       ..., 
       [ 0.30511475],
       [ 0.29620361],
       [ 0.28952026]]), '__header__': 'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: MACI64, Created on: Tue Dec  3 20:15:00 2013', '__globals__': []}
```

The command `len(data)` gives me 4, which is a surprise, since the length of the list should be 5001.
This must be a misinterpretation of the output of the command **len**.

My pseudocode suggestion for plotting

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as pp
ar = np.arange(5001) # number of data points in the brackets
pp.plot(ar, data, 'x') # TODO dimensions not matching here
pp.show()
```

**What is one way to plot the data with respect to time?**

Comment: `len(dict())` gives you the number of elements stored in the dictionary. So it is doing exactly what it is supposed to do. You want the number of elements stored under the key 'data'. You could do  `n_elem = len(data['data'])` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what our trying is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io
data = scipy.io.loadmat('arrytmia_data_bad.mat')
x = data['data']

plt.plot(x, linestyle='', marker='x')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please, see my extension to your answer. I get the AttributeError that the function object has no attribute show.

Comment: I got completely empty picture: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-26%20at%2014.52.14.png although the data is this https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/62073194/arrytmia_data_bad.mat

Comment: Thank you! I was so blind so I did not see that.